# Errors while installing Magento on Cent OS with Nginx and PHP-FPM

Tags: magento, nginx, php

I have been fighting this for hours now and finally found a resolution so I wanted to share it with anyone else who has trouble.

If you receive the following errors while installing Magento on Linux while running Nginx and PHP-FPM then try the answer below:

```
PHP extension "dom" must be loaded.
PHP extension "mcrypt" must be loaded.
PHP extension "gd" must be loaded.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running:

```
yum install php-xml php-gd php-mcrypt
```

I was wondering why this wasn't working and I was dumbfounded for hours.

The trick is to restart php-fpm once you have everything installed. I kept restarting Nginx.

Run the following:

```
service php-fpm restart
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: `service php5-fpm restart` worked for me (notice the 5 in there).